# Sending the following JSON to Mailchimp API 3.0 -- Getting errors, what am I missing?

Tags: json, curl, google-apps-script, mailchimp

I am trying to submit the following JSON to my list. I am working so that people who donate to our 501(c)(3) charity automatically get emailed a receipt for tax purposes, and signed up to our "Donors" list so that we can notify them in the future of new resources and campaigns.

This is being submitted with Google App Scripts UrlFetchApp.fetch. In order to read the error message, I submitted my JSON with curl. I have gone back to what I tried a few days ago, using the way Google claims I am supposed to submit JSON and specify specific parameters for URLFetchApp.fetch.

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "Authorization": "Basic loginname:apikey",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "payload": {
        "status": "subscribed",
        "email_address": "email@example.com",
        "merge_fields": {
            "FNAME": "Tony",
            "LNAME": "Blackmon"
        }
    }
}
```

The Method and Authorization are for URLFetchApp.fetch to know that it is a POST request, and what authentication to send. The only thing being sent to MailChimp is the "payload" JSON object supposedly (according to Google Documentation).

If I submit just the payload object using curl it appears to work without issue. When I say it seems to work, my list stays empty, but if I rerun the curl command a second time, I am told the user is already on the list. I waited for a few minutes, and verified that the user is indeed on the list.

I am getting an error back from running the Google App Script though, that makes no sense. Let me go and delete my user, and run it again, and see what I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out... Here is all of my code to send to MailChimp:

```
function sendToMailChimp(first_name, last_name, email_address){

  var loginKey = Utilities.base64Encode("bch:" + API_KEY);

  var payload = {"status":"subscribed",
                 "email_address":email_address,
                 "merge_fields":{
                      "FNAME":first_name, 
                       "LNAME":last_name}};

  var payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

  var options = {"method":"POST",
                 "headers":{ "Authorization":"Basic " + loginKey},
                 "Content-Type":"application/json",
                 "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
                 "payload":payload }; 

  //var options = JSON.stringify(options);

  Logger.log(options);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mc_base_url,options);
  Logger.log(response);

}
```

That commented line JSON.stringify for "options" did not need to happen. It was making URLFetchApp.fetch mess up its options. Instead, I just need to JSON.stringify the payload. Now that I have wasted two days on this, hopefully if anyone else runs into this issue they will be able to get past it because of this post.